# Set executable rpath to install prefix in cmake

Tags: glibc, dynamic-linking, cpack, rpath

I have an application which use some external libraries and I don't want to install these libraries to system. And my program required `glibc` version which was not installed on the target system, I have to ship custom version of `glibc` along with my application. My application written in C++ and used CMake as build system. I also use CPack to package my application along with dependencies in to RPM.

These was steps that I did:

- set install prefix to `/opt/myapp` by set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`
- built custom `glibc` and installed into my computer (developer's computer)
- built binary, check for library dependencies using `ldd` command
- copy all dependencies into `lib` folder in my project, using `INSTALL(FILE...)` to install them into `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib`
- use `patchelf` to patch binary interpreter into `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/ld.so`

There is one more step I need to do to get my application work, that is set `rpath` to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib`. But if I use `patchelf`, CPack does not allow me to package my application. I have to set `rpath` to the binary *after* installed.

I know this is very ad-hoc solution, what is better solution?